# Pandas conditional creation of a dataframe column: based on multiple conditions max

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

I have a df:

```
  dog1  dog2  cat1  cat2  ant1  ant2
0    1     2     3     4     5     6
1    1     2     3     4     0     0
2    3     3     3     3     3     3
3    4     3     2     1     1     0
```

I want to add a new column based on the following conditions:

```
 if   max(dog1, dog2) > max(cat1, cat2) > max(ant1, ant2) ----->   2
 elif max(dog1, dog2) > max(cat1, cat2)                   ----->   1
 elif max(dog1, dog2) < max(cat1, cat2) < max(ant1, ant2) ----->  -2
 elif max(dog1, dog2) < max(cat1, cat2)                   ----->  -1
 else                                                     ----->   0
```

So it should become this:

```
  dog1  dog2  cat1  cat2  ant1  ant2   new
0    1     2     3     4     5     6    -2
1    1     2     3     4     0     0    -1
2    3     3     3     3     3     3     0
3    4     3     2     1     1     0     2
```

I know how to do it with [straightforward condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526169/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-dataframe-column-based-on-multiple-conditions?noredirect=1#comment110575722_62526169), but not this kind with max. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.max(axis=1)` function in pandas for it:

```
conditions = [
       (df[['dog1','dog2']].max(axis=1) > df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1)) & (df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1) > df[['ant1','ant2']].max(axis=1)), 
       (df[['dog1','dog2']].max(axis=1) > df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1)),
       (df[['dog1','dog2']].max(axis=1) < df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1)) & (df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1) < df[['ant1','ant2']].max(axis=1)), 
       (df[['dog1','dog2']].max(axis=1) < df[['cat1','cat2']].max(axis=1))]
choices = [2,1,-2,-1]
df['new'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

output:

```
   dog1  dog2  cat1  cat2  ant1  ant2  new
0     1     2     3     4     5     6   -2
1     1     2     3     4     0     0   -1
2     3     3     3     3     3     3    0
3     4     3     2     1     1     0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
def newrow(dog1,dog2,cat1,cat2,ant1,ant2):
    if max(dog1, dog2) > max(cat1, cat2) > max(ant1, ant2):
        return 2
    elif max(dog1, dog2) > max(cat1, cat2):
        return 1
    elif max(dog1, dog2) < max(cat1, cat2) < max(ant1, ant2):
        return -2
    elif max(dog1, dog2) < max(cat1, cat2):
        return -1
    return 0

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: newrow(*x), axis=1)
```

The new df will be

```
  dog1  dog2  cat1  cat2  ant1  ant2  new
0     1     2     3     4     5     6   -2
1     1     2     3     4     0     0   -1
2     3     3     3     3     3     3    0
3     4     3     2     1     1     0    2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you looking for np.maximum().
Try to find it out at [numpy maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)
Hope it help.