# Pandas conditional comparison: based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a df

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  
0     1     2     3     4    
1     2     2     3     4    
2     3     4     3     5   
3     4     3     2     1
```

And I want to add a new column based on:

```
if (col1 & col2) < (col3 & col4) --- > 2
```

I followed the approach similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526606/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-dataframe-column-based-on-multiple-conditions/), just without `max()` as follow but all didn't work:

```
df[['col1','col2']] < df[['col3','col4']] 

(df['col1'] and df['col2']) < (df['col3'] and df['col4'])
```

What's the correct way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask = df[['col1','col2']].max(1) < df[['col3','col4']].min(1)

df['new_col'] = np.where(mask, 2, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  new_col
0     1     2     3     4      2.0
1     2     2     3     4      2.0
2     3     4     3     5      NaN
3     4     3     2     1      NaN
```

Comment: just changed the first condition to max (instead of min), didn't think of it this way lol....

Comment: Hi Quang. Please refrain from adding "IIUC" to every answer if you can. There are several editing principles behind this: (1) it is redundant and reflexive, and does not add anything to the post; (2) it indicates some uncertainty on your part, and you may wish to clarify that in the comments before answering, and (3) where an answer is accepted, it removes the doubt about whether you understood it correctly.

Comment: With all of that in mind, this material would classify as (conversational) ["fluff" that we remove here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Thanks!